# Unable to get JQuery to return AJAX data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm relatively new to JQuery, so before I try to build the actual app, I'm trying to build a simple Ajax script that'll simply return the data.

However, despite more or less copying and pasting the code, I still can't get it to work.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>This is a title!</title>

<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
alert ('1'); 

$.ajax({
 url: 'process.php',
 dataType: "html",
 success: function(data) {
$('#testsite').html(data);
alert('Load was performed.');
}
});

alert ('2'); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='login'>
 <div id='testsite'>
</div>
<input type='button' id='lsubmit' value='Submit' />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The JQuery script is definitely loaded, process.php is definitely called up (it creates a text file just to prove that it has in fact been run) but anything echo'd in the process.php doesn't get sent through as data.

It's probably something simple, but I've run out of ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: does `alert('Load was performed.');` get executed? I would recommend installing Firebug - it shows you exactly what requests are happening under the covers.

Comment: did you try to set dataType to text in the ajax query?

Comment: The Load was Performed alert box does get triggered.

Comment: And I just tried setting it to text and it still doesn't work =/

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with your code assuming process.php indeed is at the same path as this script and is outputting something.. Perhaps you could put up a live example somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this was major stupidity on my part. I messed up the process.php file so it didn't have any data to return

I have no memory of doing this and no idea why I did. Sorry for wasting your time and thanks to all those that helped =]

Comment: as others said , firebug is very nice tool. It shows you the ajax call the resonse from process.php and you can easily notice the error. If you are use ie , please use fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add an error handler, see if that gets fired, and inspect the error that is happening....  Add a callback to error.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these

$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});

$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});

even you solve yur problem , you can try these